# Laravel 5.2 route:cache changes my url() output

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I came accross a strange behavior from Laravel 5.2 and i would like to know if this happened to anyone else or only on my bad luck.

I have a function called optimize:

```
function optimize()
{
    $url = url('backend');
    \Artisan::call('route:cache');
    \Artisan::call('config:cache');

    return redirect()->to($url)->withMessage(_t('system_optimized'))->withMsgtype('success');

}
```

If i output the $url var then i get something like:
http://devhost.dev/Cartaki/backend but if i output url('backend'); after the Artisan calls then i get something like this: http://devhost.dev/backend.

I solve this issue by using the $url var as a path to the redirect()->to() method but the problem is there.

Another strange thing is that my flash message will not show up after the redirection. If i comment out the artisan calls, then my flash message will show up as expected.

Any thoughts on this one?

Comment: Why are you making those `Artisan::call` calls to begin with? This is really odd.

Comment: The `Artisan` facade interacts with the Console Kernel. Not surprising to see that it jacks up a web environment. Remove your `Artisan::call` lines completely, and maybe back up, and explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: :D 
This is a place in the admin area of an application where i can create controllers, models etc from a web ui. 
The artisan calls are there to cache the routes after the application was edited.

Apart from the ethics of using the commands... any ideas?

Comment: Yeah. `exec('php artisan optimize');` =)

Comment: Seriously though. You're trying to make Laravel bootstrap the console kernel environment from an already booted web environment... of course it's going to be messy. This is ugly, don't do it. Rethink your approach.

Comment: Thanks! exec did it! 
This is ugly but it will run once or twice. 
Thanks for the hint!